# Big data file, manupulation and search

Tags: mysql, bash, bigdata

I have two files of data. The first is a dump file which is very huge (more than 6Gb) and contains records from a database. The second is a list of strings(one string each line) I have to find partial matches in lines of the other file(about 50k lines). So far I did some manipulation on the first file in bash. I have printed the first field(which contains the useful information for me) to a new file than removed the first 25 lines which contains just comments and generated string and after that I made a unique sort (unique is needed because there can be duplication in the first field value and I thought that ordering by letter maybe fasten the search). It takes about half hour to generate that on my laptop. In the end the file contains one string each line and has about 10^8 lines.

```
awk '{print $1}' dump > first
sed '1,25d' first > temp_data
sort -u temp_data > data
```

Now I have to find the partial matches(or at least the their count) for all strings in the smaller file from the bigger. First I thought that I will do it with bash and run the following code:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} {s=$1; for (i in a) if (index(i, $1)) s=s FS i; if (s!=$1) print s}' serach_strings data > result
```

But it looked like it will run forever so I decided to try to load the files into mysql(loading the bigger file took about half hour) and tried to run with several teststrings:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE name LIKE '%teststring%';
```

It takes about 30 seconds, so if I count for the 50k search that would take about 17 days which is not acceptable, cause I have to run this whole thing every couple days.

So the question is that how can I achieve that result more effectively in couple of hours. Currently I'm testing this on my laptop, but I have a desktop computer, I can install a server version Linux on it, which can be used to run just this task. What are the most important characteristics for that task(processor speed, core number, memory)?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: as you don't seem to be using files `first & temp_data` except to create your final file `data`, you should be able to make the first section run faster by pipelining and using `awk` to eliminate the first 25 lines. i.e. `awk 'NR>26 {print $1}' dump | sort -u > data`. Also man `fgrep`, maybe `fgrep -f listfile data > found` might help, although 50K lines for fgrep might be too much. When faced with this a long time ago, I compiled a version of fgrep with a much larger buffer than the standard, and that worked fine. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, this will help, I will play with it, I thought that this method can be fasten somehow by skipping to make these files, but my first problem is analyzing the data, when I'm ok with that than I will use your opinion to optimize the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below approach:

Step1: If you are using mysql version5.6 then you can keep your data table either innodb or myisam but if you are using lower version then keep your table myisam.

Step2: Create a fulltext index on column in which you are searching your string.

Step3: Create a stored procedure, which will keep your all strings in a cursor from 2nd table and search one by one from data table and store count in any table, either you can update in 2nd table against various strings or you can insert in any new table.

---

Addition in Answer:

If you share table size, table schema, server configuration then I can help you. Further you can try below-

Command to create full text index:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD FULLTEXT(mycoloumn);
```

If you are facing problem to alter the table then can change below variables:

```
tmp_table_size                = 1G
max_heap_table_size           = 1G
max_allowed_packet            = 64M
key_buffer_size               = 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = half of your RAM
```

Note: For it you have sufficient RAM in your machine.

After changing them restart your mysql and try alter and after alter you can change these variables as per your requirement.

Comment: Step1: I use mysql 5.6.12, so the table can remain in InnoDB

Step2: I tried to add a fulltext index, my machine worked about 5 hours when I had to stop it. I even had to modify some variables in the mysql.ini to start it. Will this end sometime and I just have to wait more? What charasteristics of the machine are most important to do this task (cpu/ram)?...

Comment: Please check in addition in answer, if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

So, after your initial manipulations, you have a large file of unique strings and a file of 50k search strings (I assume these are also unique).

You could sort them and look for duplicates:

```
sort serach_strings data | uniq -d
```

Comment: Your initial statements are true, but the code you entered does not help to achieve what I want to.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`MATCH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match). If your table has a full-text index, and you load the patterns too into another table, you can try something like:

```
SELECT pattern, COUNT(*)
FROM data, patterns
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST (pattern);
```

I would test it first running with only 10 or so rows in the `patterns` table.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will try when I will be able to add the fulltext index to the table...